# Resources and guidelines for porting an object database + data to a relational database

Tags: relational-database, object-oriented-database

Does anyone have any pointers to information on techniques for object database to relational database conversion?

I've done the standard searches and have only come up with [Data Conversion from Object-Oriented to Relational database](http://appsrv.cse.cuhk.edu.hk/~acm-hk/activity/pg/cityu-ptpang.pdf) so far.  It's a good paper, but I was hoping for more....

Answer (score 0):

I should have that here somewhere, let me look, it should be somewhere close to that paper *Upgrading from c# to cobol* :)

Basically all documentation on ORM technology (like Hibernate, Toplink) can help you. You'll probably run into issues getting good performance, handling behaviour, and object versions.

[edit]
An object database for a c program? Or a persistence engine (like ctree?)

[edit2]
So it's not an object database but a persistence engine, no object versions, storing of behaviour? Then the general style could be of a network or hierarchical database. What API do you have? Can you intercept calls?

Comment: Have you ever seen a Win32 C program that accesses a hand rolled object database via an executable runtime with via a C API (and the database has run out space and can't be extended?) I have, unfortunately.....

Comment: If the runtime uses c-tree the developers went to great lengths (successfully) to keep any c-tree stuff from leaking into the run-time API.  My best guess, is that this is someone's idea for allowing post-hoc extensibility while not providing enough information to allow someone to reverse engineer the software.

Comment: Sorry, if I wasn't being clear.  It really is an object database.  It has objects, classes, inheritance and methods that are serialized into the data store (which I was speculating might have been implemented using c-tree ISAM).  As far as I can tell, the db is not based on a commercial product and has a fixed maximum size baked into it (which my client is butting up against).  The DB runtime was developed (as a redistributable) specifically for an  application that was extensively customized for my client and I don't have access to the sources for the db runtime or the people who wrote it.

Answer (score 0):

Which ODBMS are you converting from? If it's simply a matter of scalability or functionality you should consider moving to a commercial ODBMS or db4objects. If the application uses an ODBMS because an RDBMS wasn't performing well then moving back to one probably isn't a good idea. If you have to move to an RDBMS for another reason I'd look at Hibernate, but there will be a performance penalty and you'll have to maintain the mapping layer forever.

Comment: As far as I can tell, it's not a commercial ODBMS.  It appears to have been developed for a specific product and baked into a redistributable runtime.